# Slack API: select conversation members while filtering out bots without n+1

Tags: slack, slack-api

I need to select all members of a conversation who are not bots. It appears the way to do this is to first call [`conversations.members`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.members) and then for each member call [`users.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info). Using the slack ruby client, that boils down to this:

```rb
client = Slack::Web::Client.new(token: "MY-OAUTH-TOKEN")

# returns an array of user ids
response = client.conversations_members(channel: "#some-channel", limit: 500)
member_ids = response.members

members = member_ids.reject do |member_id|
  # returns a https://api.slack.com/types/user object
  user = client.users_info(user: member_id)
  user["user"]["is_bot"] == true
end
```

This obviously presents an `n+1` problem. I'm wondering if I've overlooked a better API method to call, or an API method argument that could help with this, whether via slack-ruby-client, or just via the vanilla API methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Currently Slack does not have a single API call solution to your problem statement.

Comment: Thanks. I have also confirmed this with Slack support. The only way currently is what I described in the OP